# Behavior of cache for www.abc.com//index.html type of url

Tags: http, url, caching

HI i am implementing a HTTP cache, which will be a URL based caching.The problem I am facing is I am unable to decide, weather **www.abc.com/index.html** and **www.abc.com//index.html** should be cached as different objects. What does the RFC say about the behavior?

Currently I am caching them as different objects. I am dependent on other module for getting the hostname. for **www.abc.com/index.html Hostname = abc.com**  and for **www.abc.com//index.html Hostname = index.html**

Comment: These are not complete URIs. Fix them and retry (the other modules may start returning the expected results then).

Comment: Is this expected to change the hostname in such cases ?